# Android Studio only creates fragement url, not fragment class

Tags: android-fragments

In Android Studio, when I click on my package in java folder => new => Fragment => Fragment (blank),
I only get the XML layout from the fragment, not the Fragment-class.

Is this a bug? (it worked fine on another computer yesterday, if I recall correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with Android Studio 0.8

When I add a new => Fragment = Fragment(Blank ), I get two files.
an XML layout file.
and
a Class file.

I was trying to recreate your issue, but I always get a class file, even if I do not get an XML layout file.  So I would say you have something strange going on.

What flavor/version of IDE are  you using?